# Random "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile." error from Google Analytics API v3

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am receiving this error randomly when I am trying to send a request to Google Analytics API v3:

> "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."

From every 8-10 times that I try a same request (same parameters, authentication, etc.), I receive this error only once and the other times I receive the correct response in the other times. The other strange part is that we are handling many clients and I only have seen this error for only handful of our clients.

For more background, we are using [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) NPM package to send our Google Analytics API requests.

This is parameters that I am sending to the API:

```
{
  params: {
    auth: OAuth2Client {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      transporter: DefaultTransporter {},
      credentials: [Object],
      eagerRefreshThresholdMillis: 300000,
      forceRefreshOnFailure: false,
      certificateCache: {},
      certificateExpiry: null,
      certificateCacheFormat: 'PEM',
      refreshTokenPromises: Map {},
      _clientId: 'XXXXX,
      _clientSecret: 'XXXX',
      redirectUri: 'postmessage'
    },
    ids: 'ga:XXXX',
    metrics: 'ga:sessions,ga:bounces,ga:transactions,ga:transactionRevenue,ga:goalCompletionsAll',
    dimensions: 'ga:date',
    'start-date': '2021-10-01',
    'end-date': '2021-10-20',
    samplingLevel: 'HIGHER_PRECISION',
    quotaUser: 'XXX'
  }
}

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return google
            .analytics({ version: "v3"})
            .data.ga.get(params, (error, { data: response } = {}) => {
                if (error) {
                    return reject(new Error(`Google API sent the following error: ${error}`));
                }
                return resolve(response);
            });
    })
```

Authentication:

```
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, "postmessage");

oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);

await oauth2Client.getRequestHeaders().catch((error) => {
            throw error;
});
```

And then passing `oauth2Client` in the params as `auth`.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: How are you authorizing this code?

Comment: @DaImTo just updated the question, thank you!

Comment: I think you should have a look at the google drive api sample for node.js.  your auth code doesnt look right to me https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. In my case I was using the same object of `oauth2Client` for multiple API requests but was calling these lines before each request:

```
oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
await oauth2Client.getRequestHeaders();
```

This could potentially change the token that I was passing in the request parameters, `params`,  before it was being sent.

So in other words if you are sending multiple requests to the API at the same time, it is better to generate the token once and use the same token for all those requests.